# Authentication in Restful web service

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, restful-authentication

Below is my web.xml file which contains authentication of web service.

```
<sec:authentication-manager>
        <sec:authentication-provider>
            <sec:user-service id="userService">
                <sec:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="admin" />
                <sec:user name="report" password="report" authorities="customer" />
                <sec:user name="johndoe" password="password" authorities="customer, admin" />
            </sec:user-service>
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <sec:http create-session="stateless" use-expressions="true" path-type="regex">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/services.*" access="permitAll" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/services/fichier.*" access="hasRole('customer')" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/services.*" access="hasRole('admin')" />
        <sec:http-basic />
    </sec:http>
```

Now I have specified one user - `report` which has one role - `customer`. This user can access only services under fichier. So patter is `/services/fichier.*`.

Below is the specific method :-

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('customer')")
@GET
@Path("/downloadFile/{fileName}/")
public String downloadFile(@PathParam("fileName") String fileName, @QueryParam("fileId") Integer fileId)
{
    return "blah blah blah"
}
```

Now my URL is - `http://localhost:8080/AutoFIE2Web/services/fichier/downloadFile/ffffff.jpg?fileId=5`

I have used `report` user which gives me access denied exception, but it does work with other two users - `admin`, `johndoe`.

What is the wrong with this authentication ?

Thanks

Comment: Just try to replace the ``@PreAuthorize("hasRole('customer')")`` with ``@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('customer')")``

Comment: Then try to move  the line ``<sec:intercept-url pattern="/services.*" access="hasRole('admin')" />`` upper then the line ``<sec:intercept-url pattern="/services.*" access="hasRole('admin')" />``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<sec:http create-session="stateless" use-expressions="true" path-type="regex">
       <!-- <sec:intercept-url pattern="/services.*" access="permitAll" /> -->
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/services/fichier.*" access="hasRole('customer')" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/services.*" access="hasRole('admin')" />
        <sec:http-basic />
</sec:http>
```

After removing `permitAll` access, it is working fine.